# how to use mel expression on salesforce result to extract single value

Tags: mule, mule-component

I'm new to salesforce using mule. I want to retrieve value and assign it to a flowVar from the result set returned by the Salesforce query. I tried using `payload.HeadCount`, `payload['HeadCount']` and `payload[0].HeadCount` none of them are worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share your result set.

Comment: @star salesforce returns the data like Employee Count, Department Id, HeadCount with sample data like 123, 10, 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Boss, 

Salesforce returns `org.mule.streaming.ConsumerIterator` as a payload which in turn implements `java.util.iterator`, so, either you can use `next()` operation followed by the `field name`(in your case `HeadCount`) or convert the payload into `java.util.ArrayList` and set it as `payload` using `#[org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils.toList(payload)]` and then iterate the `payload` same as java.

In short, you can try with the below MEL 
`#[payload.hasNext() ? payload.next().Headcount: "something else"]`

Comment: thank you very much for the quick response. It worked for me, you saved my time.